# How to select a specific overload of a method?

Tags: f#

I'm calling a C# API which uses overloads and optional parameters.
Unfortunately, one of the overloads is a `params object[]` and F# selects it over a more specific overload which I intend to call. How do I make F# select the overload I want?

[Here's a small repro](https://sharplab.io/#v2:DYLgZgzgNALiBOBXAdlAJiA1AHwPYAcBTZAAgGUBPCGQgWwFgAoA48qm2gOgBkBLZAI6cAogA988QhAi9cyCEyYwKRciQC8TEtpLUAhjF4BjErToAjQvBIAxXLgAUhcZOmzkIEmIlSZcgDw2KEb+/DAAfOFQJAD8AOZxntTw/HEAlBokWjo5AETOPm5yudna+oYmZrSW1naOANr+AAp68Hq0AILwbRThALokrXEQnrjmAFb1fRnqWYw5efit7RCD3XoUJYxMjcLIMPAUTbhh/UzAhDCmevxrcQBuGqUkAPQvJAAqABa8qxJhq1ySzatFWrR6uWi5kQVwAkiQAO56fYkXhXGC4Ej/FH5Fy+dxbHIXK6uRDAK6zMicOoOMAoEgODIAWnCJAAzNFcrk0s9sTAwKRcgBSCC5Eik8nPAAMTCAA===). [And here is a link to the actual API](https://getakka.net/api/Akka.Actor.Props.html#Akka_Actor_Props_Create__1_System_Linq_Expressions_Expression_System_Func___0___Akka_Actor_SupervisorStrategy_).

```ml
open System
open System.Linq.Expressions

type S =
    static member Foo(expression: Expression<Func<int>>, ?gg: string) = 
        "expression"
    static member Foo([<ParamArray>] args: obj[]) = 
        "params array"

[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv =
    // This prints "params array", but I want it to print "expression"
    let result = S.Foo(fun () -> 3, "")
    printfn "%s" result
    0
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To call the expression version with two arguments, you need:

```ml
let result = S.Foo((fun () -> 3), "")
```

In your code, you've actually defined a function that returns a `(3, "")` tuple, which is only a single argument.

Comment: Haha, that was silly. I had another issue to solve in my real code, but that was a first step in the right direction. Thank you.